# How to loop over a column in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm quite new to R. I have a `df` with a `V1` column. I would like to create a loop to calculate the ratio (cuf-off values).

I want to take the first number 1 and divide by 301 and put the value in a `df$V2`. Then I want to sum first two numbers and divide by 301 etc.

```
For example:
                                                V2
1/301 (first value of df)                     0.0033
2/301 (sum of the first two values of df)     0.0066
2/301 (sum of the first three values of df)   0.0066  


df

V1

1
1
0
0
1
0
1
1
1
0
```

Comment: Can you show the full expected output

Answer (score 1):

You can take cumulative sum of `V1` values and divide it by 301.

```
df$V2 <- cumsum(df$V1)/301
df

#   V1      V2
#1   1 0.00332
#2   1 0.00664
#3   0 0.00664
#4   0 0.00664
#5   1 0.00997
#6   0 0.00997
#7   1 0.01329
#8   1 0.01661
#9   1 0.01993
#10  0 0.01993
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `transform` to create the 'V2' by dividing the cumulative sum of 'V1' with 301

```
df <- transform(df, V2 = cumsum(V1)/301)
```

-output

```
df
#   V1          V2
#1   1 0.003322259
#2   1 0.006644518
#3   0 0.006644518
#4   0 0.006644518
#5   1 0.009966777
#6   0 0.009966777
#7   1 0.013289037
#8   1 0.016611296
#9   1 0.019933555
#10  0 0.019933555
```

---

Or another option is `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE`

```
transform(df, V2 = Reduce(`+`, V1, accumulate = TRUE)/301)
```

---

Or if we need to loop, loop over the sequence of rows, then assign each value of 'V2' by the `sum` of the sequence of elements from 1 to that row of 'V1' divided by 301

```
df$V2 <- 0
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
       df$V2[i] <- sum(df$V1[1:i])/301
 }
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(V2 = cumsum(V1)/301)
```

---

Or using `accumulate`

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
   mutate(V2 = accumulate(V1, `+`)/301)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame",
     row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```